# Remove Running DM Welcome Message Bot in Twitter

Tags: ruby, twitter, twurl

i have installed(?) a welcome message bot in my twitter dm. yesterday i regenerate the api because i forgot where i saved them. now i can not delete or edit my current welcome message. i have deleted both the project and application also disconected the app from my account still the same.

when i use this with my new api from my new app from my new project

`twurl authorize --consumer-key iFGe1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --consumer-secret 8ZsaMxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

it says Authorization successful

but when i want to see message id

`twurl -X GET "/1.1/direct_messages/welcome_messages/rules/list.json"`

it says

> {"errors":[{"code":89,"message":"Invalid or expired token."}]}

same with adding new message and upload media

i have emailed twitter about this, they reply is to report them to advertising. when im not using twitter for business, the link they sent itself said You do not have access to any advertiser account

is it possible to remove or reset the current welcome message? thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: have you authorized this app (twurl / your consumer key) to your account? Does your app have read/write/direct message permissions?

Comment: what im saying is im not able to edit or delete or anything my welcome message. i dont know if it because i regenerated the api or not. i have tried everything i can find on google but it still show the same error message. i already deleted the project, created new one and still shows the same error message

Comment: yes andy, i have that read/write/direct message permissions since i already have welcome message with media, on the old project and app AND the new project and app